# How to uninstall python

Tags: python, version, uninstallation

I am an amateur and have a mac and I would like to reset all python. I want to delete all the versions other than the one already on the mac in the OS. I would like the python versions to be as if I had just gotten a new OS.

THanks!!!

Comment: And what other versions have you installed? How did you install them?

Comment: Do you also want to uninstall any third-party packages that you installed into Apple's Python?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no one-size-fits all answer here, because there are a number of different ways to *install* Python, many of which do not come with uninstallers.

Everything Apple installs is inside `/System`, or inside `/usr` but not `/usr/local`. So, those are the areas not to touch, no matter what.

Apple's Pythons put their system-wide site packages in `/Library/Python/X.Y`. Some third-party Pythons may *also* use site packages there. If you've mixed and matched, there's no way to straighten that up except to wipe the whole thing. To restore these directories to a clean slate, each one should have nothing but a `site-packages` directory, in which there should be nothing but a `README` and a `easy-install.pth` and/or `Extras.pth`.

Some third-party packages that have binary installers meant to work with Apple's Python install things into  `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. Again, these are shared with other Python installations. If you want to restore to a clean slate, delete everything in any such directory.

If you've configured user-specific site packages, or virtual environments, you should know which ones go with which Python—and, if you don't, just scrap them entirely.

Apple's Pythons install or link any scripts/executables that come with any site packages into `/usr/local/bin`. Unfortunately, most third-party Pythons will do the same thing. And of course non-Python executables installed from elsewhere also end up here. The only way to really be safe is to only delete files here that:

- Are symlinks to something in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` or into a site-packages directory.
- Are scripts whose shebang lines points to a non-Apple Python (that is, it's not in `/System` or `/usr/bin`).
- Are executables that link to a non-Apple Python (visible with `otool -L`).

If you're also trying to kill site packages installed into Apple Python, symlinks, shebangs, and executable links that point to Apple Python can go too.

---

Anything installed with a package manager—Homebrew, MacPorts, Fink, etc.—should be uninstalled the same way: `brew uninstall python`, `sudo port uninstall python3.2`, etc.

Anything that has an uninstaller (either inside a `Python X.Y` or `MacPython` or similar folder in `Applications`, or on the original disk image), obviously run that.

Meanwhile, non-Apple standard framework builds—that is, any binary installer from python.org, or anything you build yourself according to simple instructions—will put files into the following places:

- `/Library/Framework/Python.framework/X.Y`. This is the main guts. Kill it. In fact, kill the whole `Python.framework` to remove all versions at once.
- /usr/local/bin, shared with Apple, as mentioned above.
- /usr/local/lib. Anything named libpython* here is killable.
- /Applications/[Mac]Python*.

Non-framework builds by default install everything into /usr/local; they will be effectively the same as framework builds, but with no `/Library/Framework/Python.framework/X.Y`, and instead a `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y` that contains things besides just site-packages. Kill those things.

---

Third-party installations like Enthought or (x,y), you will have to figure out what you have and find the uninstallation instructions on their site. There's really no way around that.